Must understand headers error in Spring Boot SOAP Client
i'm new to programming and i'm trying to code a SOAP client in spring boot. I have configured a WebServiceTemplate, with interceptors for both request and response, using a keystore and truststore.
That's my config class:
`@Configuration
public class SOAPConfiguration implements SOAPHandler {
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.smartqonta.faceclient.generated");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) throws Exception {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("https://webservice.face.gob.es");
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(new HttpComponentsMessageSender(this.createHttpClient()));
    webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[] {
            this.requestInterceptor(), this.responseInterceptor()
    });
    return webServiceTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor requestInterceptor() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(getRequestCrypto());
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Signature");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType("32699832");
    securityInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementMustUnderstand(true);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("{c2f5028b-0a60-459b-a41c-f96a438af971}");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionKeyIdentifier("X509KeyIdentifier");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureDigestAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts(
            "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security");
    return securityInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor responseInterceptor() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("Signature");
    securityInterceptor.setValidationSignatureCrypto(getResponseCrypto());
    return securityInterceptor;
}

private Crypto getRequestCrypto() throws Exception {
    CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(new ClassPathResource("/keystore.jks"));
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword("32699832");
    cryptoFactoryBean.setDefaultX509Alias("{c2f5028b-0a60-459b-a41c-f96a438af971}");
    cryptoFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return cryptoFactoryBean.getObject();
}

private Crypto getResponseCrypto() throws Exception {
    CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(new ClassPathResource("/truststore.jks"));
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword("32699832");
    cryptoFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return cryptoFactoryBean.getObject();

}

private CloseableHttpClient createHttpClient() throws Exception {
    return HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(this.sslContext()).build();
}

private SSLContext sslContext() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/truststore.jks"), "32699832".toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/keystore.jks"), "32699832".toCharArray());
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "32699832".toCharArray());

    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

    return sslContext;
}

}`
And this is my rest controller, calling the webservice:
`@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class restController extends WebServiceGatewaySupport{
@Autowired
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

public static String URL = "https://webservice.face.gob.es/facturasspp2";

@GetMapping("/test")
public void test(){
    FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyService service = new FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyService();
    FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort port = service.getFacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort();
    

    Object response = getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(restController.URL, port.consultarAdministraciones());
    System.out.println("********Respuesta: " + response);
}

}This is my pom.xml: 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>`

And, this is the error i get:
jakarta.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood at com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MUTube.createMUSOAPFaultException(MUTube.java:95) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube.processResponse(ClientMUTube.java:65) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1117) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1020) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:989) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:847) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:431) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:160) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:62) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:132) ~[rt-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy95.consultarAdministraciones(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] at com.smartqonta.faceclient.controllers.restController.test(restController.java:31) ~[classes/:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]      at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
Thanks in advance!!
